# WebPack displaying tslint warning on main page

Tags: angular, webpack, tslint

I've been upgrading to webpack 2, but now I cant display main page as I end up with the warning message:

Failed to compile:

./src/app/login/login.component.ts
[20, 21]: missing whitespace

This is the one of the warning messages that I see in console,
but it never stopped webpack server from displaying content before.

In Console webpack says: "Compiled with warnings" so there should not be reason for displaying Failed to compile on the main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it :)

Actually it was a bug with webpack:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/861

Work around is to set:

```
devServer: {
  overlay: {
    warnings: false,
    errors: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are executing a linter during compiling. It is ESLint or TSLint, depending on your programming language (Javascript/Typescript). It skips compiling after the execution of the linter as it detected style issues in your code.

Do you have any of these dependencies in your package.json?

```
"devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "4.1.1",
        "eslint-loader": "1.8.0"
    }
```

Look in your webpack.config.js, there could be something like this defined which executes ESLint during compiling:

```
module: {
   rules: [
           {
            enforce: "pre",
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "eslint-loader"
           }
   ]
}
```

Please feel free to accept it as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: this is what I have in webpack config:
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [{loader: 'tslint-loader', options: {typeCheck: true}}],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        enforce: "pre"
      },

Comment: I guess tslint is configured to fail the build even its only a warning. You can configure TSLint by providing a tslint.json at the root level of your project. Maybe you already have it and set failOnHint: true?
See the official documentation: npmjs.com/package/tslint-loader

Comment: issue was with the webpack configuration rather than tslint